# Examples of sans-serif fonts for commercial use and with mathematical support

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, math-fonts, opentype

I'm a designer and I'm designing a visual identity for a client, but he requested that the fonts have a wide math support. He uses LaTeX, and I would like to know some free fonts for commercial use that are sans serif, mathematically supported, and have a wide variety of families (bold, semi-bold, italic, light, regular, etc.). Can you list for me some fonts you use or know of?

P.S.: I have never used LaTeX, so I don't really understand the use of fonts in it.

Comment: You might want to look at the [fonts with math support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643318/examples-of-sans-serif-fonts-for-commercial-use-and-with-mathematical-support) page of the LaTeX font catalogue. There's only a handful of sans serif fonts: Arev, CM Bright, LX Fonts. But are you using LaTeX for your part of the work? If you need something typically packaged as ttf or otf with unicode math support there really isn't much to choose from. [Fira Math](https://github.com/firamath/firamath) might be the best you'll find.

Comment: The [0.4 beta prerelease of Fira Math](https://github.com/firamath/firamath/releases/tag/v0.4-beta-3) has other weights (Heavy, SemiBold, Ultra, ExtraLight, etc.).